# Whats is the difference between this 2 syntax in ES6?

Tags: ecmascript-6

what is the difference between: 
`const MY_CONST = ()=>()`
and 
`const MY_CONST = ()=>{}`
?. Thank you.

Comment: I should add that both forms of syntax make Javascript less readable than the versions that don't use the shortcut syntax.  Fewer characters does not always make better code.  People seem to be enamored with new ES6 shortcuts and are forgetting that it's more important to always write easily readable code, even if it takes you a few more bytes of code to to it.  Arrow functions have their purpose and their place, but that doesn't mean they should be used everywhere.  Same with auto-returns from arrow functions.  Sometimes adding the `return` keyword makes the code a lot more readable.

Comment: it is a great advice. I'll keep it in mind. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `const MY_CONST = () => {}` syntax is very similar to `const MY_CONST = function() { }`.
the `() => ()` is called **object literal expression** and used for returning an object like this example:

```
const MY_CONST = params => ({foo: bar})
```

see more details here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

https://www.sitepoint.com/es6-arrow-functions-new-fat-concise-syntax-javascript/